# Interpreting random effects estimate in logistic regression with binary predictor

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, random-variable

I've run a model in R as follows:

```
model1 <- glmer(outcome ~ predictor + (1 | groupID), data, family = binomial())
```

Like `outcome`, `predictor` is a binary variable. My understanding is that this model would only give me the random effects estimate of groups where `predictor = 0` (because 0 would be the intercept), so I also ran the following to include a slope term and hopefully estimate the variance of groups where `predictor = 1`:

```
model2 <- glmer(outcome ~ predictor + (predictor | groupID), data, 
                family = binomial())
```

I ran a dotplot using the 'lattice' package and was confused about seeing the same groups in both intercept and slope plots. I don't understand what the slope estimate plot is telling me.

How do I get a random effects estimate for all groups or those for which `predictor == 1`?

I think a problem might be that all individuals within each group have the same value of `predictor`.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few things going on at once here: your first model estimates random effects for all `groupID`. What it *prints* in the summary is the estimated standard deviation across blocks, which is of interest in the marginal model.

If you want to get individual random effect estimates, you can use `lme4::ranef(model1)` to extract them. This will return the random intercepts, one per `groupID` in your input.

Your second model indeed adds a random "slope" on `predictor` (assuming it's coded 0/1), but the marginal estimate will still be the same for all observations. If you want to plot the individual *random* effects you'll have to extract  them as above.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I have another question related to this, but I thought I should probably not ask it here. In case you are up for answering another, it's here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629081/why-do-my-random-effects-estimates-not-match-the-data